# Как называется этот разъем DC и где найти распиновку?

Tags: электроника

Пытаюсь оживить древнючий жесткий диск (внешний) WD2500b012, но куда то потерялся блок питания, купить новый очень дорого и долго (да и нигде почти нет), хочу подключить от универсального (проводами).
Для этого надо понять, что подключать и куда. (распиновка).
Вынуть диск и подключить напрямую к компу пытался, но там диск IDE и переходники работают очень криво, поэтому нужно выяснить про этот разъем, буду рад любым советам.
Спасибо!

[image: ОПИСАНИЕ НУЖНО ДЛЯ DC]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Video ?

Comment: Похоже ты его разобрал. Там не видно что ле какие контакты куда идут? А вообще есть внешние корпуса (или док-станции) для hdd китайские. Вроде не очень дорогие должны быть.

Comment: может так? http://poweradapter.co/new-sunfone-ac-power-supply-acu038a0512-5v-12v-22a-4-pin-mini-din-p-6356.html

Comment: Да разобрал, мне хочется перекачать с него и выкинуть его:) по контактам не видно, что кого питает, могу выслать фотки плат

Comment: а авометром его? )) я такие в отрочестве припаивал 100-ватным паяльнегом ))

Answer (score 0):

Это DIN - они бывают 1001 вариантов - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector). 
[Тут](http://www.cablesandconnectors.com/26500-26.HTM) есть такой как у вас.

Вообще DIN - универсальный разъем, он не предполагает какой-то жесткой <s>распальцовки</s> распиновки - как к<s>и</s>етайцы припаяли так и будет :-)
В СССР DIN часто применялся как аудио-разъем, в том числе для подключения акустики.

Comment: Если подключу 12 вольт, какие варианты это все сжечь?